# Not able to identify check box based on the name given beside it using xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I wanted to identify the `CheckBox` based on the name given to it by using the `xpath`, but was not able to reach till the text uniquely.

The html code is in below. How can I get the dynamic xpath for 'text1' or 'text2' mentioned in the html?

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="section-content">
<div>
<input class="cls" type="checkbox"/>
 text1        
</div>
</div>

<div class="section-content">
<div>
<input class="cls" type="checkbox"/>
text2        
</div>
</div>

<div class="section-content">
<div>
<input class="cls" type="checkbox"/>
text3        
</div>
</div>

<div class="section-content">
<div>
<input class="cls" type="checkbox"/>
 text4        
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'text4')]/input")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the node with text as **text1** you can use the following line of code :

```
WebElement element_text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section-content']/div[contains(normalize-space(), 'text1')]"));
```

To get identify the **Check Box** associated with the node with text as **text1** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section-content']/div[contains(normalize-space(), 'text1')]/input"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
WebElement body = dr.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));
    List<WebElement> div = dr.findElements(By.className("section-content"));
    for(int i=1;i<div.size();i++)
    {
        String checkBoxText = dr.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div["+i+"]/div")).getText();
        if(checkBoxText.equals("text3"))
        {
            dr.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div["+i+"]/div/input")).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using an XPath that starts at the HTML tag is very brittle. Any change to the DOM will break that locator

Comment: yes, am aware of that...He provided with sample page...So I provided a small workaround.